# Change text of Apply button in Google Job posting (Indexing api)

Tags: indexing, google-indexing-api

When I posted job on Google using their indexing api, it appears in Google jobs but the text on apply button is 'apply on xyz.domain.pqr' instead of my Company name. How to change this text of make it 'apply on xyx' where xyz is my Company name.

Answer (score 1):

So, finally after a lot of thinking and digging I found the answer.

What actually happens is, when you post a job Google needs to associate that job to your organization. So for this it hits your domain (base url of your job url). If this base url is not indexed in Google then Google picks up the domain instead and hence puts 'apply on xyx.domain.pqr' because http://xyz.domain.pqr is not indexed on Google.

So first you should index the base url which has the name of your Company in title tag.

After that index your job page.

You will get 'apply on YourCompanyName' in Google.

P.s: If you want to check your base url is indexed or not, check it in url inspection section of Google Search Console.